# JSON de-serialization using jackson

Tags: java, json, json-deserialization, jackson2

I've a JSON which I want to deserialize to java object. I tried but failed to succeed. Really appreciate if somebody help it. I was getting below error.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
// Note : vairable 'body' is the JSON string which I've shared below.
RpcResponse rs = mapper.readValue(body, RpcResponse.class);
```

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
>   deserialize instance of `Result` out of START_ARRAY token

```
{
"error": null,
"id": "12345",
"result": {
    "inventory": [{
        "history": [{
            "when": "2012-08-30T07:28:51Z",
            "changes": [{
                "removed": "",
                "added": "1",
                "field_name": "qty"
            },
            {
                "removed": "normal",
                "added": "major",
                "field_name": "popularity"
            }],
        "id": 474599,
        "alias": null
    }]
}
```

}

Here are the java classes

```
public class RpcResponse {

private String error;
private String id;
private Map<String, Result> result;

public String getError() {
    return error;
}

public void setError(String error) {
    this.error = error;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Result getResult() {
    return result;
}

public void setResult(Result result) {
    this.result = result;
}
```

}

```
public class Result {

private Map<String, List<Inventory>> inventory;

public Map<String, List<Inventory>> getBugs() {
    return inventory;
}

public void setBugs(Map<String, List<Inventory>> inventory) {
    this.inventory = inventory;
}
```

}

```
public class Inventory {

private String id;
private String alias;
private Map<String, List<History>> history;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getAlias() {
    return alias;
}

public void setAlias(String alias) {
    this.alias = alias;
}

public Map<String, List<History>> getHistory() {
    return history;
}

public void setHistory(Map<String, List<History>> history) {
    this.history = history;
}
```

}

```
public class History {

private String who;
private String when;
private Map<String, Changes> changes;

public String getWho() {
    return who;
}
public void setWho(String who) {
    this.who = who;
}
public String getWhen() {
    return when;
}
public void setWhen(String when) {
    this.when = when;
}
public Map<String, Changes> getChanges() {
    return changes;
}
public void setChanges(Map<String, Changes> changes) {
    this.changes = changes;
}
```

}

Comment: where is the code you're using to deserialize?

Comment: you should edit your question and add that class. it's not easy to read in the comment section

Comment: Your example code doesn't compile -- therefore it's a lie to claim that it throws that exception.

Comment: @slim very possibly a copy / paste error. the real issue was not having proper member types.

Comment: A copy / paste error as in "not copying the actual code he ran"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RCP Response,

```
private Map<String, Result> result;
```

should just be

```
private Result result;
```

In Result,

```
private Map<String, List<Inventory>> inventory;
```

should be

```
private List<Inventory> inventory;
```

and in Inventory,

```
private Map<String, List<History>> history;
```

should be

```
private List<History> history;
```

In History, `Map<String,Changes>` should be a `Collection<Changes>`, etc

Comment: you probably also need to change getBugs to getInventory or give jackson a hint

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question. This is the work he should have done getting the code in the question to compile before claiming that it throws a runtime exception.

Comment: the getBugs is a typo. The actual getters and setters are proper.